# Disable Yii inbuilt authentication

Tags: yii

How do I disable the Yii's inbuild authentication? ( /site/login ).

I am using an extension to do authentication and dont want to leave the inbuilt login open - potentially this could be a security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just remove the actions in the site controller for login and logout, i.e `actionLogin()` and `actionLogout()` inside the **mywebapp/protected/controllers/SiteController.php** file
 and the view for login, i.e. **mywebapp/protected/views/site/login.php**,
 and also remove the model i.e inside **mywebapp/protected/models/LoginForm.php**.
Further i would suggest you to either change the UserIdentity.php inside the **mywebapp/protected/components** folder, or remove it and write your own identity class.
If you want any tips to write your identity class, check the api at [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUserIdentity).

Comment: Additionally make the changes as @ldg has suggested

Answer (score 2):

It partly depends on how your extension is managing access control and I assume when you say "inbuilt authentication", you are referring to Gii-generated files.

If you remove/comment out the `accessControl` filter in your controller file(s) as well as the `accessRules()` method for good measure, that should pretty much disable the generated access control/authentication.

Assuming your extension doesn't require them, you can remove the /views/site/login.php and /components/UserIdentity.php files and other related files as mentioned.